# Hyperledger configtx.yaml Application vs Channel section

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to understand the `configtx.yaml` file provided by the test-network in the fabric samples.

I don't understand what is the difference between the "`Application`" and "`Channel`" section.

They both include the same subsections however above the Policy one there's a slightly different comment.

On Appliction it says "`/Channel/Application/<PolicyName>`" on the other hand on Channel it states "`/Channel/<PolicyName>`".

Have I understood correctly by saying that channel section may be associated with the system channel while Application one with the application channels (that are those channels inside of the system one)?

Comment: Please go through this link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/policies/policies.html

Comment: @alpha I've already read that but I couldn't understand it anyways. Would you explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application configuration is for channels which are designed for application type transactions.

For instance, invoking a chaincode, collecting endorsements, and submitting the resulting transaction to ordering.

The non-application type transactions are internal to Fabric, and are used to coordinate channel creation.

Application section will be applicable to peers on the channel.